# Code for running the method declared in DLL

Tags: java, eclipse, dll, jna

I created a Java code that tries to access the method `LoadProject` of the class `IProjectFactory` defined in `myAPI.dll`. The description of the DLL file says: *IProjectFactory is used to load a project file into memory. IProjectFactory is a static class in the myAPI.dll assembly. It exposes the LoadProject method that takes a string containing the path to the file to load, and returns a reference to the resulting IProject. Using the IProject interface you can then manipulate the loaded project in various ways.*

```
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;

public class MyClass {

public interface IProjectFactory extends Library {
    public Object LoadProject(String fileName);
}

public MyClass() {
    //System.loadLibrary("myAPI");
    load();
}

void load() {
    String fileName = "xxx.sp";
    IProjectFactory api = (IProjectFactory) Native.loadLibrary("myAPI",IProjectFactory.class);

    try {
        Object project = api.LoadProject(fileName);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

After running this code, the following error message has been generated:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'LoadProject': The specified procedure could not be found.

    at com.sun.jna.Function.<init>(Function.java:179)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:350)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:330)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:203)
    at $Proxy0.LoadProject(Unknown Source)
```

Does it mean that `myAPI` does not contain the class IProjectFactory with the method `LoadProject`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call *functions* in native libraries with JNI or JNA. Primitive types are mapped. Certain structures are possible also. Even callback functions are possible. See JNA's mapping table.

What is impossible, by design: Getting a class or interface that was designed for a different runtime environment (like CLR) and use it seamless within the JVM.

So if you have a native procedural/functional library that just returns pointers or primitive types then you can use it quite well.

If you need to work with objects that are returned then you are out of luck. You need to run them in their native environment and find some way of interprocess communication.

Comment: I have an example written in C#. This example shows how to access LoadProject method from myAPI.dll and this works. I try to do the same thing in Java. So, if it's possible in C#, I assume it should be also possible in Java, right?

Comment: No. C# bytecode is made to run on the CLR like Java bytecode is made to run on the JVM. They are not interchangable. "DLL" may be the misleading part: In this case it is a container for C#/CLR stuff, not a function library that could be used. No surprise C# can use it. Java can't.

Comment: Ok, so do I understand correctly that there is absolutely no way to use this DLL from Java?

Comment: The interesting thing is that the description says: A .NET assembly is provided (myAPI.dll) that can be directly referenced by 3rd-party software. Note that this assembly is built to be architecture-neutral.

Comment: JNA only recognizes C/C++/assembly DLL signature. A .NET DLL uses incompatible DLL signature. For .NET C# managed DLL library, you need to interop it into a C/C++ DLL before you can you use it via JNA. There is a guide on doing this, but I could not remember where it is.

Comment: Looks interesting, I didn't know that one, but it looks like it does it only the other way round (calling Java from CLR). And: Alpha since 2009...

Comment: Managed .NET to Unmanaged C++ bridge: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2008/02/16/net-to-c-bridge.aspx

Comment: But then you still need JNI/JNA for using from Java and you will still have the same problems. In fact you would have to write the operating client in C++ (instead of C#) and find a method to transfer the raw data. Not much won there. Easiest in such situations is to write an operating client in the libraries language and expose it as a language independent service, e.g. SOAP, that can be used easily from any other client.

Comment: Regarding the comment about the libraries description: "Architecture neutral" means it can be used on all CLRs, no matter if 64 bit vs 32 bit or ARM vs Intel. "Can be referenced by 3rd-party software": A public API exists. No statement about how this has to be or can be implemented.